# Problema com PDO::FETCH_ASSOC

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Olá, pessoal.

Estou fazendo um sistema de tags para meu blog.Para pegar o id das tags, estou fazendo uma consulta usando o operador IN.
[image: Esse código retorna]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero que retorne só o array associativo.Por isso uso o PDO::FETCH_ASSOC.

```
if($sql == true) {
    $result = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Mas ele retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Models\PDO' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\r\MeusProjetos\GreenCode3\App\Models\Editor.php:61 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\r\MeusProjetos\GreenCode3\App\Controller\admin\editorController.php(45): App\Models\Editor->insert('O titulo', '13', Array, '<p>esse \xC3\xA9 o te...') #1 [internal function]: App\Controller\admin\editorController->insert('') #2 D:\xampp\htdocs\r\MeusProjetos\GreenCode3\App\Core\Core.php(101): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3 D:\xampp\htdocs\r\MeusProjetos\GreenCode3\index.php(15): App\Core\Core->run() #4 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\r\MeusProjetos\GreenCode3\App\Models\Editor.php on line 61
```

Comment: Quando você fizer a instância do PDO, coloque assim \PDO, que vai dar certo é o por causa dos namespace

Comment: Deu certo, obrigada!